# Uso get&set en división

Tags: java, poo

Alguien me puede explicar como se puede realizar esta division?

sqrt(numJuegos / 2.25)

Estoy utilizando metodos get y set en una condicion

```
if (resultados.getNumJuegos() >= 5) {
        resultados.setPuntajePorJuegos(1); 

    } else {
        resultados.setPuntajePorJuegos(Math.sqrt(resultados.getNumJuegos(/25)));
    }
```

Se que dentro del parentesis de /25 tengo que llamar a numJuegos que esta en otra clase, como puedo resolver este problema?

Gracias a todos por las respuestas. :)

---

En este caso estoy trabajando con datos enteros.

Ya intente de la manera:

resultados.setPuntajePorJuegos( Math.sqrt(resultados.getNumJuegos() / 25) );

sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Dices que trabajas con enteros, pero la raíz cuadrada devuelve un double (formato de coma flotante con doble precisión). Para que funcione necesitas quedarte con la parte entera del resultado, haciendo un casting

Answer (score 0):

Hay que recordar que un `get` es un método que devuelve el valor del miembro de la clase. A suponer, ya que no das mucha informacion... tu metodo getNumJuegos() devuelve un tipo `int`.

Teniendo presente esto puedes manipular esa expresión como un numero, teniendo esto presente, tenemos que:

```
if (resultados.getNumJuegos() >= 5) {
    resultados.setPuntajePorJuegos(1); 
} 
else {
    resultados.setPuntajePorJuegos( Math.sqrt(resultados.getNumJuegos() / 25) );
}
```